# How to ignore warnings from external C++ dependency headers in Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I am writing a C++ program using Bazel as the build tool. The program depends on some external C++ libraries. I want to add `-Werror` to my compiler option, but warnings from external headers will cause compilation failure. So I want to ignore all warnings from external dependencies.

Here is what I know:

- Using `-isystem` compiler option to specify inclusion directory can suppress warnings from that directory.
- When using `cc_library` in Bazel, the `includes` parameter specifies the directories to be add as `-isystem` dependencies.

If the external library uses the `includes` parameter to specify the include directory, then I will have no problem ignoring the warnings from that dependency.

But if the external library doesn’t use the `includes` parameter, how should I ignore warnings from that library?

Comment: Either get the library fixed so that it does not cause warnings. Or wrap the library into separate file which forward what you need but avoid the warnings in their own interface header. Ignore the/all warnings when building the "empty" wrappers. Use all warnings when building your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `external_include_paths` later in the upcoming **5.0.0** version, which was introduced by this [commit](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/08936aecb96f2937c61bdedfebcf1c5a41a0786d)

There is also a opening tracking [issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12009)